# Trick the reflector

Tags: java

There is a piece of java code that I did not write and I can't change that uses the reflector to call a class' method. Something like this (I haven't seen the code):

```
    ....
    params[0] = Something;
    ....
    Class c = Class.forName(Name);
    Method m = c.getDeclaredMethod(MethodName, pt);
    if (Modifier.isStatic(m.getModifiers()))
    {
        res = m.invoke(null, params);
    }
    else
    {
        obj = c.newInstance();
        res = m.invoke(obj, params);
    }
    ....
```

So far so good.

I control the class' name, the method's name and the parameters. I can send any combination of those, there is a catch though: The first parameter is hard-coded, so any parameter that I send is appended to the params array. So the method has to accept that parameter.

My question is: Is there a way to create a type and use it in there? Something like this:

```
    public class PrintWrapper {
        public static void println(Somethingtype Something, String arg) {
            System.out.println(arg);
        }
    }
```

I tried using that as the Class name, but it didn't work, any idea? I need some sort of anonymous class or something.

And no, I can't change the source code or add a class to the system. The only things I control is the class' name, the method's name and the rest of the parameters.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you're trying to do.

Comment: What is `pt` - you need to include this for your question to make sense.

Comment: pt is an array of Class objects that identify the method's formal parameter types, in declared order. That is handled by the ellipsis ... :D . And it works

Comment: Yes, but you don't let us know what the first entry is...

Comment: Do you want to *hack* an online-judge system or something like that?

Comment: Do you mean MethodName? That is a string with anything I want. I can use "println" for example, but the problem is that println is not expecting a parameter of type Somethingtype.

Comment: Can u you use 

    params[0].getClass()

to figure out the type of first parameter if that is not provided in 'pt' and then add this class type to 'pt' before the invocation to 

`c.getDeclaredMethod(MethodName, pt)

Comment: I don't want to hack anything. I am dealing with a poorly written, 3rd-party, unmaintained API.

Comment: *I tried using that as the Class name, but it didn't work* - what didn't work? Did nothing happen? Did it throw an exception? What?

Comment: I know the type of params[0] and it is already in pt (that is done in the ellipsis too :D )

Comment: It fails in this way: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: java.lang.System.out.println(SomethingType, java.lang.String)

Comment: Or like this: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: public class PrintWrapper { public static void println(Somethingtype Something, String arg) { System/out/println(arg);}}

Comment: Not sure I understand, but what if you just create a class with a method that takes Object as its first parameter, and whatever else you really want as the rest of the parameters, then call the actuall method you want to call from there, e.g. System.out.println(...)?

Comment: I can't create a class, that is the problem. The only thing I can do is to send the class name, the method name and the parameters to this function that executes the reflector.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The only things I control is the class' name, the method's name and the rest of the parameters.

then is the answer:

> there is NO way to create a type and use it in there?

Comment: Too bad. Let me reform the question: Do you think there is a way to execute methods that don't have that something as input?

Comment: If I knew I would not have asked :D

Comment: what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I want to be able to run a method of a class. But right now I can do that if the method accepts that first parameter.

Comment: you can only invoke method which exist

Comment: Yes. Unless I can create an anonymous function or something like that.